# Dash datatable with select all checkbox?

Tags: plotly-dash

I am wondering if anyone have an idea on how to create a "Select all" checkbox in Dash Datatable (it should be in the red box area)? The idea is it will select all the rows available in the datatable.

[image]

I have read through the entire Datatable documentation (https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/interactivity) and there is no mention of this. Trying to search online also failed.

I remember dash-tables-experiment has this functionality but it has since been deprecated. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Currently this option is not supported within a `dash_table.DataTable` element. However, there is a workaround by adding two `dbc.Button()` parts to your Dash `layout`, the first for *selecting all* and the second for *deselecting all*. Then have an `@app.callback` that (de)selects all once the button is clicked.

You will get something like this:

No rows selected:[image: No row selected]

All rows selected after button click:
[image: All rows selected after click]

The callback on its turn would look something like the following (thanks to @neilpanchal in [this git issue](https://github.com/plotly/dash-table/issues/249#issuecomment-693131768)):

```py
from loguru import logger
import dash
...

@app.callback(
    [Output('df-table', 'selected_rows')],
    [
        Input('select-all-button', 'n_clicks'),
        Input('deselect-all-button', 'n_clicks')
    ],
    [
        State('df-table', 'data'),
        State('df-table', 'derived_virtual_data'),
        State('df-table', 'derived_virtual_selected_rows')
    ]
)
def select_all(select_n_clicks, deselect_n_clicks, original_rows, filtered_rows, selected_rows):
    ctx = dash.callback_context.triggered[0]
    ctx_caller = ctx['prop_id']
    if filtered_rows is not None:
        if ctx_caller == 'select-all-button.n_clicks':
            logger.info("Selecting all rows..")
            selected_ids = [row for row in filtered_rows]
            return [[i for i, row in enumerate(original_rows) if row in selected_ids]]
        if ctx_caller == 'deselect-all-button.n_clicks':
            logger.info("Deselecting all rows..")
            return [[]]
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
```

Comment: What is 'PreventUpdate"? RIght now dash is raising an error saying NameError: name 'PreventUpdate' is not defined

Comment: @KansaiRobot In certain situations, you don't want to update the callback output. You can achieve this by raising a PreventUpdate exception in the callback function: `from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate`